# Exiting to top-level shell from within a nested sourced script?

Tags: bash

I want to provide a trap that exits from a `bash` script if it was sourced rather than executed, but I want to provide the trap in another (library) file that is sourced. Scripts might be organised like this:

```
a        sourced by code external to the library
+--b     sourced by a
   +-- c sourced by b
```

There may be many levels of nesting (more than one file like `b`). The `c` file needs to contain code that will make `a` exit gracefully (and with a nonzero exit status set by `c`) if `a` is sourced.

A graceful exit is one that behaves similarly to an executed script that calls `exit`.

**When to terminate**

A `bash` script can use the `BASH_SOURCE` array to ascertain whether it was sourced itself or whether the outermost script was sourced.

The stack of scripts is avaiable as the array `${BASH_SOURCE[@]}` where the first element is the most recent script and the last is the first. Therefore it follows that:

- the current script (e.g. `c`) is `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`
- the outermost script (e.g `a`) is `${BASH_SOURCE[-1]}`
- the executable is `$0`

To assert that the current script was executed:

```
[[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "$0" ]]
```

To assert that the outermost script was executed:

```
[[ "${BASH_SOURCE[-1]" == "$0" ]]
```

So, script `c` can determine whether script `a` was executed like this:

```
[[ "${BASH_SOURCE[-1]" == "$0" ]] || terminate
```

**How to terminate**

What `c` cannot do is `terminate`. It can't `exit` because that would cause whatever sourced `a` to exit. The alternative is `return` but that only passes control back to the prior `b` script. Without `b` and, in turn, `a` co-operating, the termination would be ineffective.

This co-operation can be coded in `a` and `b` but a preferable solution would be one where `c` doesn't return control to `b` if `a` was sourced.

**Can `c` terminate `a` in an `exit`-like fashion ?**

*I am pretty convinced that this is not possible because a sourced `a` is not in its own process, but it would be great to be shown otherwise. I thought perhaps a way to manipulate the call stack so a that `return` would return from `a` but there's probably too much voodoo in such thoughts...*

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want is to pop *two* stack levels, or otherwise as many as needed to return back to the outer script. Correct?

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason that you're *executing* this code, as opposed to only *defining* it, in the context of `c`? Having `c` define a function that's documented to be invoked with a calling convention akin to `init || return` wouldn't be too far from idiomatic.

Comment: the idea is that `a` would source `b` and the trap would happen _as if by magic_ without the coder of `a` having to give it any thought.

Comment: If `b` runs `init || return`, where `c` defines `init`, then we're good; the developer of `a` doesn't need to care.

Comment: that's the _co-operation_ that I was referring to. It would need to be coded in all `b` (there may be many `b`, all different).

Comment: *nod*. I'm not sure that you're going to get a better solution without doing something ugly (a transient DEBUG trap or such). YMMV, but in my mind it's better to be a bit un-DRY than to be going with ugly hacks that are likely to break debuggers and limit compatibility between shell releases. But then, it may be that one of the other greybeards in the tag will come up with something I'm missing.